# Best way to sum all values of a SparseIntArray

Tags: android, kotlin, sparse-matrix

What is the best way to sum all the values of a `SparseIntArray` in `Kotlin` ?

I try something but it's not working...
This is my code (`quantities` is the `SparseIntArray`) :

```
var amount = 0
for (q in quantities){
     amount += q
}
```

But I have this error :

```
For loop range must have an 'iterator()' method
```

Be careful : my problem don't concern `ArrayList` but `SparseIntArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this manually:

```
var amount = 0
for (i in 0 until quantities.size()) {
    amount += quantities.valueAt(i)
}
```

If you use [android-ktx](https://github.com/android/android-ktx/blob/master/src/main/java/androidx/core/util/SparseIntArray.kt), you can also rewrite this as:

```
var amount = 0
quantities.forEach { k, v -> amount += v }
```

Comment: thanks! it work! just a suggestion, you have to write size with '()' -> size()

Comment: Right, I've corrected the answer. `size` without parentheses can also be used with android-ktx